# Cannot get Azure DocumentDB to work with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having difficultly using DocumentDB to create documents using visual studio 2015 update 2 and Vb.net

The call to CreateDocumentAsync goes away and never comes back. I've attempted the same calls in C# using the same parameters and they work fine, but my customer requires that i use Vb.NET

I've reduced the problem down to a test program which is shown below.

**Main.vb**

```
Imports Microsoft.Azure.Documents
Imports Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client

Module Module1


    Sub Main()
        Test()
    End Sub

    Public Async Sub Test()

        Dim client As New DocumentClient(New Uri("https://XXXXXXX.documents.azure.com:443/"), "XXXXXXXXX==")


        ' Create a new document


        Dim x As New JGR
        x.id = Guid.NewGuid.ToString()
        x.name = "Graham"
        Dim y As ResourceResponse(Of Document) = Await        client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("XXXX-Playground", "XXXXXX"), x, Nothing, True)
     End Sub
End Module
```

**JGR.VB**

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class JGR

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="id")>
    Property id As String
    Property name As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to run just fine. I've created a new single partition collection and tested with Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB nuget package 1.7.1 with Newtonsoft.Json version  6.0.8. I've also tried updating to Newtonsoft.json 8.0.3, still runs fine. The request charge for creating the document is 5.52

I would recommend you to change the method signature from Sub to Function which returns task, in order to capture errors - if not the program may exit before your request is completed.

```
Sub Main()
    Test().Wait()
End Sub

Public Async Function Test() As Task
    Dim client As New DocumentClient(New Uri("https://stacktest.documents.azure.com:443/"), "g6YlmeYQkoIlrKhuToNIF7kDeHn5VSKiljx4FOijNUtae25cEyNwnKO5TXCT7Y2yWifldxwKb8AIZWhaAtQ5tw==")


    ' Create a new document

    Dim x As New JGR
    x.id = Guid.NewGuid.ToString()
    x.name = "Graham"
    Dim y As ResourceResponse(Of Document) = Await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("db1", "col1"), x, Nothing, True)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - it turns out that i was missing an exception of - {"Message: {""Errors"":[""Owner resource does not exist""]} ... any idea what it means?

Comment: my guess would be that either the collection or database does not exist. Check your names and verify they are correct. Also verify that these resources are not deleted in Azure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I checked all that, think it might be time to remove both of them and try and recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VB programmer so I'm not entirely familiar with Async in VB, but I am pretty sure that the problem is with the Async code.  When you call a Sub there is no return Task so your code won't wait for any of the Async operations to finish.

You can wrap it in a Task and call your method like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim task = New Task(AddressOf Test)
    task.Start()
    task.Wait()
End Sub
```

This should solve the problem.  However, it is very verbose.  An alternative is to change the Sub to a Function and return a Task with some sort of status message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - this helped me get the exception :-)